# What is the use of the multiple random appended characters after ASPSESSIONID?

Tags: session, cookies, asp-classic

I have noticed this on several cookies that I have collected over time from different sites. The cookie will be named: `ASPSESSIONIDAQSDTADTG` or something similar. I realize that ASP appends these randomly generated characters onto the end of the cookie base: `ASPSESSIONID` 
but I have never come across the reason why. It's probably something simple I missed, but a search online did not give me the answer. I realize that these cookies try to differentiate themselves from each other, but why is this a requirement of ASP classic? Why is this different than ASP.NET's standard ASP.NET_SessionId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is old question but I will leave my 5 cents tip. I found a [reference](http://www.securiteam.com/windowsntfocus/6C00L003GA.html) for this matter.

```
| ASPSESSIONID |            JHSDFEKK            | KJSHFWEJNDFSERFWERKJNLKE |
|--------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------|
| cookie name  | IIS process number transformed |     session instance     |
```

But I couldn't find official resource.

Answer (score 0):

### Sessions

HTTP is a stateless protocol. This means HTTP servers would respond to each client request without relating that request to previous or subsequent requests. [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) introduced state management mechanism to HTTP.

This RFC basically introduced two header directives: Cookie and Set-Cookie. Set-cookie directive sets the session cookie and sends to the client browser indicating beginning of a session. From now on each request from this browser would contain Cookie directive in the header which indicates that the request is part of the current session.

### Session management in ASP session and concerns

[image]

When the first request comes from the client browser, it marks the beginning of a new session. This means that a session object is created and a session id is assigned to this session object on the server. This session id is now sent to the browser in an encrypted form as a session cookie. The browser will store this cookie in memory for entire duration until the browser is closed. Each subsequent request from the browser will send this cookie as part of the header. The server on receiving the cookie will know the corresponding session id and hence the sessions object.

The session ID is a read-only value that uniquely identifies the current clients to the Web server. In classic ASP, session IDs are assigned in a sequential manner i.e., the session ID 981249305 is followed by the session ID 981249306, and so on. The session cookie for session ID 981249305 would be stored on the client machine as the cookie

```
ASPSESSIONIDJHSDFEKK=KJSHFWEJNDFSERFWERKJNLKE
```

Classic ASP does not support any method to enforce the change of cookie value.

So, answering your question, this "randomly generated characters" it's a way to generate a cookie that never existed before.

Comment: I fully understand how sessions work and the creation of session cookies. The characters that I'm talking about specifically are "JHSDFEKK" on the left hand side. Unless I wasn't following your answer correctly, I believe you described the actual value of the session cookie as opposed to the naming conventions of the cookie. Could you update your answer and focus on the naming convention rather than how sessions work? Thanks.

Comment: like I said:

"Answering your question, this "randomly generated characters" it's a way to generate a cookie that never existed before."

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Why does ASP classic require cookies to be named uniquely. How does this contrast with ASP.NET's uniform ASP.NET_SessionId?